# onResponse Method not called of Response.listener

Tags: android, android-volley

I am new in volley and try to develop a chat app for this I use post method for login in so when I post from postman the PHP code run well(using slim), and when I tried the same with Android The onResponse() method is not run but the onResponseError()  run to resulted Output not come. the code be as

```
package com.example.user.gcm_chat.activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.Editable;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.text.TextWatcher;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.example.user.gcm_chat.R;
import com.example.user.gcm_chat.app.EndPoints;
import com.example.user.gcm_chat.app.MyApplication;
import com.example.user.gcm_chat.model.User;

public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private EditText inputName, inputEmail;
private TextInputLayout inputLayoutName, inputLayoutEmail;
private Button btnEnter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    if (MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().getUser() != null) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    inputLayoutName = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_name);
    inputLayoutEmail = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_email);
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_name);
    inputEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_email);
    btnEnter = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_enter);

    inputName.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputName));
    inputEmail.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher(inputEmail));

    btnEnter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            login();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * logging in user. Will make http post request with name, email
 * as parameters
 */
private void login() {
    if (!validateName()) {
        return;
    }

    if (!validateEmail()) {
        return;
    }

    final String name = inputName.getText().toString();
    final String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
            EndPoints.LOGIN, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.e(TAG, "response: " + response);

            try {
                JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(response);

                // check for error flag
                if (obj.getBoolean("error") == false) {
                    // user successfully logged in
                    JSONObject userObj = obj.getJSONObject("user");
                    User user = new User(userObj.getString("user_id"),
                            userObj.getString("name"),
                            userObj.getString("email"));

                    // storing user in shared preferences
                    MyApplication.getInstance().getPrefManager().storeUser(user);

                    // start main activity
                    startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class));
                    finish();

                } else {
                    // login error - simply toast the message
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),  obj.getJSONObject("error").getString("message"), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(TAG, "json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json parse error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            NetworkResponse networkResponse = error.networkResponse;
            Log.e(TAG, "Volley error:" + error.getMessage() + ", code: " + networkResponse);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Volley error: " + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put("name", name);
            params.put("email", email);

            Log.e(TAG, "params: " + params.toString());
            return params;
        }
    };

    //Adding request to request queue
    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq);
}

private void requestFocus(View view) {
    if (view.requestFocus()) {

getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.
  SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
    }
}

// Validating name
private boolean validateName() {
    if (inputName.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()) {
        inputLayoutName.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_name));
        requestFocus(inputName);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutName.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}

// Validating email
private boolean validateEmail() {
    String email = inputEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty() || !isValidEmail(email)) {
        inputLayoutEmail.setError(getString(R.string.err_msg_email));
        requestFocus(inputEmail);
        return false;
    } else {
        inputLayoutEmail.setErrorEnabled(false);
    }

    return true;
}

private static boolean isValidEmail(String email) {
    return !TextUtils.isEmpty(email) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches();
}

private class MyTextWatcher implements TextWatcher {

    private View view;
    private MyTextWatcher(View view) {
        this.view = view;
    }

    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
    }

    public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.input_name:
                validateName();
                break;
            case R.id.input_email:
                validateEmail();
                break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

Endpoint.java

package com.example.user.gcm_chat.app;

```
 public class EndPoints {

// localhost url -
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://localhost/gcm_chat/v1";
public static final String LOGIN = BASE_URL + "/user/login";
public static final String USER = BASE_URL + "/user/_ID_";
public static final String CHAT_ROOMS = BASE_URL + "/chat_rooms";
public static final String CHAT_THREAD = BASE_URL + "/chat_rooms/_ID_";
public static final String CHAT_ROOM_MESSAGE = BASE_URL + "/chat_rooms/_ID_/message";
}
```

Error log

> 09-25 15:15:34.758 15166-15275/com.example.user.gcm_chat E/DynamiteModule: Failed to load module descriptor class: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.dynamite.descriptors.com.google.firebase.auth.ModuleDescriptor" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.user.gcm_chat-2/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.user.gcm_chat-2/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
>   09-25 15:15:42.934 15166-15844/com.example.user.gcm_chat E/LoginActivity: params: {email=prashu1996gupta@gmail.com, name=prashu}
>   09-25 15:15:46.027 15166-15166/com.example.user.gcm_chat E/LoginActivity: Volley error:null, code: null

build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {


compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.user.gcm_chat"
    minSdkVersion 21
    targetSdkVersion 24
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
dexOptions {
    javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.1.1'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:9.0.2'
compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.1.1'

}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: As you can see from the error logs, there's no problem with the Volley implementation, the firebase Auth implementation is breaking, typically a module required for firebase auth is not found. do check your gradle dependencies once.

Comment: dependency for firebase auth? `com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.4.0` ??

Comment: please someone tell how to get Ip address of the computer on which php services are running.

Comment: Depends from system to system. Search google for your system. for linux its ifconfig in the terminal. for windows its the first ip when you ping a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have done the permission granted for all other devices.
for this go to Wamp->Apache->httpd.conf and httpd-vhosts.conf
and then change to required to granted

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the localhost give your system IP address. Localhost refers to the system. that is when app is running your mobile is the localhost and the devices should be connected on the same network. Wifi or usb tethered

```
public static final String BASE_URL = "http://[YOUR IP]/gcm_chat/v1";
```

if you are using an android emulator give IP address as 10.0.2.2

Hope this may solve your problem

Comment: I tried this, error not resolved error log shows Unexpected response code 403 for http://192.170.**.***/gcm_chat/v1/user/login and Volley error:null, code: com.android.volley.NetworkResponse@79f8757

Comment: make your project online in localhost . if you are using WAMp check this https://hsnyc.co/how-to-host-your-own-website-using-wamp-server/